# Mysq l - Slow one update query in large table

Tags: mysql

i have a three almost identical queries executed one by one in my app. Two of queries are executing fairly fast but one is much slower. Here are queries:

```
update `supremeshop_product_attributes` set `id_step` = 899 where `id_step` = 1 and `id_product` = 32641
540ms

update `supremeshop_product_attributes` set `id_step` = 1 where `id_step` = 0 and `id_product` = 32641
1.71s

update `supremeshop_product_attributes` set `id_step` = 0 where `id_step` = 899 and `id_product` = 32641
9.75ms
```

[image]

Create table query

```
CREATE TABLE `supremeshop_product_attributes` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `id_product` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `id_attribute` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `id_attribute_group` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `id_step` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `id_alias` int(9) NOT NULL,
 `price_retail` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `behaviour` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `active` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `supremeshop_product_attributes_id_product_index` (`id_product`),
 KEY `supremeshop_product_attributes_id_attribute_index` (`id_attribute`),
 KEY `supremeshop_product_attributes_id_attribute_group_index` (`id_attribute_group`),
 KEY `supremeshop_product_attributes_id_step_index` (`id_step`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3012991 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

[image]

Facts:

- table has 1500000 rows
- each query updates around 650 rows
- each searched/updated field has index (id(primary), id_product, id_step, id_alias)
- only second query takes much longer time to execute (everytime - even executed as single query not  one by one)
- each variable used in query is integer
- if i execute queries direcly in phpymysql -> sql  - i get the same execution time (like in my laravel app so query is somehow slow)

Question is why? And is there a good explanation/ fix for that problem.

For any help many thanks!
Mark.

Comment: add composite index index_name (`id_product`, `id_step`)

Comment: You're right :) It's working. 20-30ms each query. Thanks!